# UWP AutoNext Function

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player, mediaelement, playlist

I'm trying to Get a **Auto Next** method i've tried using a Index Counter but I think I misunderstand how to properly set a list using the FilePicker

The code for the FilePicker is following :

```
public async void pick_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        List<StorageFile> fileList = new List<StorageFile>();

        var fop = new FileOpenPicker();
        fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
        fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
        fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".avi");
        fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
        fop.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;

        pickedFileList = await fop.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
        // add the picked files to our existing list
        fileList.AddRange(pickedFileList);

        foreach (StorageFile file in pickedFileList)
        {
            Playlist.Items.Add(file);

            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            videoMediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
        }
        videoMediaElement.Play();
```

The Current method i have for switching tracks|Videos

```
        private async void itemclicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = e.ClickedItem as StorageFile;
        if (file != null)
        {
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            videoMediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
        }
    }
```

Empty Event im trying to use to do this.

```
  private void Element_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {



    }
```

I've looked threw all the Microsoft Sample's. Issue Being They use the `Mediaplayerelement  += Mediaplayer` And im using the MediaElement

The Answers Im looking for Can be A Resolution to my problem or assisting me in better understanding how to globally set the source of the mediaplayer using the Current or new list from the picker, Im new to all this and trying to grasp everything better Thank you!

Comment: use mediaplayerelement instead because it i newer and has a lot of functionality in it although u will need minimum sdk version as anniversary update for that to work.

Comment: with mediaplayerelement you can even use mediaplaybacklist which will make your life much simpler in this use case.

Comment: I Created a new UWP app using your code and Mediaplayer as you did and it's works as expected, are you sure that 
        var file = e.ClickedItem as StorageFile;

is getting the right file?

Comment: Its hard to Test as I need to Write a filter I can simply just change the  Playlist.Items.Add(file); to Playlist.Items.Add(file.name); but then it returns a string and not a working File. And yes I want to use the media player element sadly the required Target platform is windows 8 So I have to try and avoid the latest versions. Im just unclear how to work with the object after the Picker create's them.

Comment: @AimeeDutoit Could you please provide a sample and clarify what your issue is now and what you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking Tousee's advice to seem's he's my mentor at this stage, I used the **MediaplayerElement** and **mediaPLaybacklist**'s which made life Easier. And almost instantly fixed my problem.